# Javascript and css and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

is giving this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<style>
#div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#999;
    -webkit-transform:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
deg1=0;
deg2=0;
function animando(){
    deg1++;
    deg2++;
    quadrado = document.getElementById('div');  
    quadrado.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-2deg)";
    }
setInterval(animando(),100);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(animando(),100);
```

should be

```
setInterval(animando, 100);
```

without the `()`. You're trying to actually CALL the animando function in your code, so when the setInterVal call is prepping its arguments, the actual `<div id="div">` element has not been parsed yet, and therefore the getElementById() call returns null because the ID doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(animando(),100);
```

should be

```
setInterval(animando, 100);
```

without the `()`. You're trying to actually CALL the `animando` function in your code, so when the `setInterval` call is prepping its arguments, the actual `<div id="div">` element has not been parsed yet, and therefore the `getElementById()` call returns `null` because the ID doesn't exist (yet).